# Difference between "New-Object WindowsPrincipal([WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())" and "[WindowsPrincipal] [WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check if Powerhell script is running as Administrator.
After searching the web, I got some sample code that works fine.
In order to get the `WindowsPrincipal` object, I found two sample code as below.

First:

```bsh
New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
```

Second:

```bsh
[Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
```

The second one made me confused.

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#cast-operator--), I know that the `[ ]` is a cast operator. 
And according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/understanding-important-powershell-concepts?view=powershell-6#powershell-uses-some-c-syntax), PowerShell is built on the .NET Framework. In my opinion, this means that the above two PowerShell scripts can be converted to C#.
So I try it.
When I convert the first PowerShell script to C#. It work fine as below.

```
## First PowerShell script
New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())

// C#
var wp = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
```

But when I try to convert the second PowerShell script to C#. I get compile error. The IDE tells me that `WindowsIdentity` cannot be cast to `WindowsPrincipal`.

```
## Second PowerShell script
[Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()

// both C# code below cause compile error
var wp = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;
var wp2 = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal)System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Just as I tried on C#, the `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity` type cannot be directly converted to the `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal` type. But why is the second PowerShell script available?
Or is the `[ ]` operator in the second PowerShell script not a type conversion operator?
Maybe this operator do more than just convert object type?
What's the difference between first PowerShell script and second PowerShell script?
Did I missing any other things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: PowerShell can do **Magic**. C# can't do Magic.

PowerShell can juggle Chainsaws, bowling pins, and balls at the same time.

C# can only juggle balls if they are defined ahead of time. Trying to add a new Chainsaw into the juggling routine causes the juggler(compiler) to complain.

---

The issues are the differences between Functions, Object types, and how to cast object types.

`System.Security.Principal` is the base .NET library. The library can be used by C# and PowerShell.

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` is a function in the library.

`WindowsPrincipal` is an object type e.g. like `string` or `int`.

Calling `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` returns a `WindowsIdentity` object, which you can then use in your code.

Since `WindowsIdentity` is not necessarily the object type you want to work with, we want to use a `WindowsPrincipal` object. Unfortunately **we cannot directly cast from `WindowsIdentity` to `WindowsPrincipal` object**. We have to use the `WindowsPrincipal` constructor.

In PowerShell, you create a new object either by the `New-Object` cmdlet, or by simply using a variable for the first time. This convenience is because PowerShell is a **scripting** language, where using a variable e.g. `$a = 1` implicitly creates a new variable. e.g.

```
PS C:\> Get-Variable test
Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name 'test'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Variable test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (test:String) [Get-Variable], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetVariableCommand

PS C:\> $test = 1
PS C:\> Get-Variable test

Name                           Value
----                           -----
test                           1
```

Using the `New-Object` example:

```
New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
```

This is the right way to do it. You are creating a new object of type `WindowsPrincipal`, and passing the Windows Identity to the constructor.

The second method:

```
[Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
```

Is "wrong" because it uses casting, and earlier we stated that we cannot directly cast from `WindowsIdentity` to `WindowsPrincipal` object. So how does this work?  Well, I said earlier that PowerShell does Magic, well I'll get to that in a minute. First let's see the correct C# Code:

Calling .NET Framework specific functions in C# do differ in Syntax than PowerShell. And the reason for the specific compile error you are getting is because we are trying to cast the object, which we can't.

The example:

```
using System.Security.Principal;
var wp = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() as WindowsPrincipal; // compile error
```

The Compiler translates it to:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

Run function `GetCurrent()`

```
as WindowsPrincipal;
```

Expect a return type of `WindowsPrincipal` <-- compile time error. The compile error is because the function does not return a type of `WindowsPrincipal`, instead it returns a type `WindowsIdentity`.

Second example is also a variation that doesn't work because it can't cast the object directly. e.g.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
var wp = (WindowsPrincipal) WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); // compile error
```

The Compiler translates it to:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

Run function `GetCurrent()` and return with the `WindowsIdentity` object.

```
(WindowsPrincipal) WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Take the `WindowsIdentity` object and directly cast it to a `WindowsPrincipal` type, which it can't.

The **correct** C# code also needs the `new` keyword is:

```
var wp = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
```

The Compiler translates it to:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

Run function `GetCurrent()` and return with the `WindowsIdentity` object.

```
new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
```

Create a new `WindowsPrincipal` object passing the `WindowsIdentity` object into the constructor. Which now works.

So why does the second example:

```
[Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
```

Work in PowerShell by doing something that is "wrong"? Because PowerShell is a scripting language, and is interpreted on the fly, and can use **Magic**, it can interpret the above and perform some [Type Conversion Magic](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/) Quote:

1. **Direct assignment.** If your input is directly assignable, simply cast your input to that type.
2. **Language-based conversion.** These language-based conversions are done when the target type is void, Boolean, String, Array, Hashtable, PSReference (i.e.: [ref]), XmlDocument (i.e.: [xml]). Delegate (to support ScriptBlock to Delegate conversions), and Enum.
3. **Parse conversion.** If the target type defines a Parse() method that takes that input, use that.
4. **Static Create conversion.** If the target type defines a static ::Create() method that takes that input, use that.
5. **Constructor conversion.** If the target type defines a constructor that takes your input, use that.
6. **Cast conversion.** If the target type defines a implicit or explicit cast operator from the source type, use that. If the source type defines an implicit or explicit cast operator to the target type, use that.
7. **IConvertible conversion.** If the source type defines an IConvertible implementation that knows how to convert to the target type, use that.
8. **IDictionary conversion.** If the source type is an IDictionary (i.e.: Hashtable), try to create an instance of the destination type using its default constructor, and then use the names and values in the IDictionary to set properties on the source object.
9. **PSObject property conversion.** If the source type is a PSObject, try to create an instance of the destination type using its default constructor, and then use the property names and values in the PSObject to set properties on the source object. . If a name maps to a method instead of a property, invoke that method with the value as its argument.
10. **TypeConverter conversion.** If there is a registered TypeConverter or PSTypeConverter that can handle the conversion, do that. You can register a TypeConverter through a types.ps1xml file (see: $pshome\Types.ps1xml), or through Update-TypeData.

Basically, whenever you do a type conversion in PowerShell, it will perform Magic and try each method to convert the type dynamically on the fly for you. That is why it can handle you throwing a new Chainsaw or bowling pin at the juggler. PowerShell can interpret that we aren't trying to convert a chainsaw into a ball, and instead that a chainsaw is just another object, and we already know how to juggle objects.

This interpretation isn't a part of .NET, and so C# can't do that, and we have to explicitly define everything, and do everything correctly. This means that you can convert all C# and .NET code *into* valid PowerShell code, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please forgive me for a bad description of the problem. English is not my native language.
My question is about the second PowerShell script, which uses type conversions that don't work in C#.
I am trying to improve the description of my problem. I hope it will be easier to understand now.

Comment: Please see my (heavy) edits. I misinterpreted what was asked and realized the issue was around how PowerShell and C# handle type conversion.